# How to make shadows invisble for one object to another object?

Tags: materials, objects, shaders, shadows

How to make shadows invisble for one object to another object ? I want ONLY make this two object have shadow-hide relationships, all of the other object ever can shadow be or be shadow on this two. I can't find solution, please any master help, thanks!

Comment: Hello, have you tried with the compositor? Also maybe show a drawing that explains what you want

Answer (score 0):

Like @moonboots said the compositor is probably one of the easiest ways to do this.

Add the object you want to control the shadow cast of to it's own collection.

The scene in question:

[image: the scene in question]

The outliner setup:

[image]

Then go above the outliner change the current name to "All objects" or something, add a new ViewLayer, and then change that name to "Masked object" or something.

[image]

Then on the "MaskedObject" layer, click the check box on the object collection that you want to remove from the scene.

[image]

While this viewlayer is still active, go to the View Layer Properties panel and activate Object Cryptomatte.

[image]

Then render. It will render both versions of your scene.

In the compositor use a setup like this:

[image]

The cryptomatte mask looks something like this, only masking out the one object we want to "miss" the shadow from the monkey.
[image]

Use that as the alpha to blend the two renders and you will get a result like this:

[image]